# Alternate responses to priestly blessing

Tags: birchas-kohanim

Please explain the response to the priestly blessing that starts "כן יהי רצון" but adds b’zchut Avraham, then b’zchut Yitzchak and finally b’zchut Ya’akov

When did this tradition begin, what is its history?